# Compress hex data

Tags: c, compression, hex

For university I have the exercise to compress a series of data. In one file there is the input data and I have to write another one with the compressed data. The task is only to store the difference between the numbers. Until now I have the written the code that stores the data in an array and stores the same in the output file. Now I want to start with the compression, but have no clue how to do it. Did I store the data type?

The input file could look like this:
C9 CB C7 C0 C0 C8 C9 C9 BE 00 04

So the output file has to look like this:
C9 C2 90 8C 81 08 BE 80 04

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: input.txt output.txt\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *input, *output;
    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    int c;
    unsigned int values[100] = { 0 };

    int i = 0;
    if (input != NULL)
    {
        printf("Values:\n");
        while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
        {
            values[i] = c;
            putchar(c);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(input);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File could not be opened.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (output != NULL)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (j; j < i; j++)
        {
            putc(values[j], output);
        }
        fclose(output);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not generate output file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: There are many compression algorithms.  It is not obvious from code's input/output sample what algorithm code is using - it certainly is not "difference between the numbers".  Post the algorithm's name or more details.  [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel–Ziv–Welch)?

Comment: If I unterstand it correct I have to split 8 Bit into 2 x 4 Bit and differences should be 4 Bit. The amount of data should only be reduced if the number of bits is smaller than the number of bits of the initial value.

Comment: Please explain how you get `C2` as the second byte of your output, and how you decompress `C9 C2` to get `C9 CB ...`.